# Add element in ListView and refresh not working

Tags: android-listview, android-arrayadapter, listviewitem

I want to add element in ListView, when I click on a button. I search too much for this, but couldn't get resolved the issue.

If you want I can't send you the code, what exactly I want.

```
package com.example.listrefreshdemo;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private EditText editText;
private Button button;
private String[] myStringArray = null;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = null;
ListView listView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myStringArray = new String[] { "hello", "hi" };
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myStringArray);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);

}

private OnClickListener buttonClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String toAdd = editText.getText().toString().trim();
        if (toAdd.length() > 0) {
            editText.setText("");
            String[] tempArray = new String[myStringArray.length + 1];
            int i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < myStringArray.length; i++)
                tempArray[i] = myStringArray[i];
            tempArray[i] = toAdd;
            myStringArray = tempArray;
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        editText.setText("");
    }
};
}
```

Comment: Please include the code here.

Comment: @xpda: i added the code, please check it

Comment: I'm not sure about the android, but you can usually add a string to a listview with `listview.items.add(stringname)`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try with custom adapter for listView.
You can find example of listview with custom adapter and updating the listview [here](https://github.com/asnehal/ListViewExample.git).